# Hypervisor compatibility

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-8-emulator

I'm trying to run a simple Windows Phone 8.1 app in Visual Studio 2015.  I'm getting the error:

> Error DEP6100 unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage Connecting to the device Exception - 0x80131500 Windows Phone App

I've run coreinfo on my Asus notebook and see the following:

```
Coreinfo.exe /v

Coreinfo v3.31 - Dump information on system CPU and memory topology
Copyright (C) 2008-2014 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Note: Coreinfo must be executed on a system without a hypervisor running for
accurate results.

Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-5010U CPU @ 2.10GHz
Intel64 Family 6 Model 61 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel
Microcode signature: 00000022
HYPERVISOR      *       Hypervisor is present
VMX             -       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
EPT             -       Supports Intel extended page tables (SLAT)
```

I don't understand the American Megatrends 2.17.1249 BIOS has a setting on the Advanced tab for Intel Virtualization Technology and it's enabled.

Does the - for VMX and EPT mean there's no Hyper-v support after all?  I bought this laptop after checking for the virtualization setting in the BIOS.

Comment: which laptop do you use? Load default BIOS/UEFI settings and look if it works now

Comment: It's an Asus F555LA.  I haven't changed any BIOS settings.  Virtualization Technology is enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Run systeminfo.exe in an admin cmd or PowerShell window.  Towards the bottom, it should tell you Hyper-V's state.  The Hyper-V docs have a little bit more information about hardware compatibility ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/quick_start/walkthrough_compatibility#verify-hardware-compatibility)).

Comment: It's saying that A hypervisor has been detected.  Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.  In the meantime I've been able to run my Virtual windows phone in the hypervisor.  For some reason it's not working in the Visual Studio IDE.